# How do I protect properties from certain users in a FormRequest?

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I have several models in a Laravel/Backpack app where write access to certain properties is restricted to certain user roles.

Say I have a model `Client` with the properties

- `name`
- `phone`
- `active`
- `viewCount`

I want users with regular user privileges to be able to edit the `name` and `phone` properties but not `active` and `viewCount`. However, administrators should be able to edit `active`, and super duper administrators should have full access to `viewCount`.

I have this sorted out on the UI level and now want to implement basic security in the backend.

I would like to **silently filter out (unset) properties** that the current user is not allowed to edit, but may have maliciously set in the request.

I've been pointed to a custom `FormRequest` class being the place for this, but am a little lost how to implement it.

Should I take the pre-generated

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'nullable|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
        .....
```

and return a different array of validation rules depending on the current user's permissions? Is there a validation rule that unsets a field?

Or is there a more elegant way to handle this inside the `FormRequest` class?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass in additional rule for different user role, and as long as you use the `validated` inputs, all should be good and any inputs not specified in the rules will not in the the validated result,
e.i.
for using Form validation

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'nullable|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
    ];

    // Additional rule only for administrator or super admin
    if ( $this->user()->howEverYouFilterTheRole() )
        $rules['active'] = 'nullable';

    // additional rule only for superAdmin
    if ( $this->user()->howEverYouFilterTheRole() )
        $rules['viewCount'] = 'nullable';

    return $rules;
}
```

then just the call in the `validated` method of the request

```
public function store( WhatEverFormRequest $request ) {

    // Only contains field input specific in the rules;
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```

**OR**
apply the rule directly on request

```
public function store( Request $request ) {

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'nullable|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
    ];

    // Additional rule only for administrator or super admin
    if ( $request->user()->howEverYouFilterTheRole() )
        $rules['active'] = 'nullable';

    // additional rule only for superAdmin
    if ( $request->user()->howEverYouFilterTheRole() )
        $rules['viewCount'] = 'nullable';

    // Only contains inputs specified in rules
    $validated =  $request->validate( $rules );


}
```

Another options you could use would be the rules; [prohibited-if](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited-if), [prohibited-unless](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited-unless), [exclude-if](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-if), [exclude-unless](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-unless)

Comment: I would also recommend to use [`exclude_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-if), so you have a set of rules and just exclude the ones you should not be validating, so you end up with a simple array